# Existence of right hand limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that $\frac{\sin x} {x}$ tends to $1$ as $x \to 0$. Then why it's said that $\frac{\sin [x]} {[x]}$ is not defined, as $x \to 0^+$. But it exists and is equal to 1. x belongs to (-1,1).
([x] is greatest integer less than or equal to x.)
I don't understand why they say, it's not defined.
Does this limit exist and equal to 1?

Comment: How is $[x]$ defined?

Comment: Assuming that $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer function (i.e., floor function), for $0 \leq x < 1$, we have $[x] = 0$. So it involves division by zero, which renders the expression $\sin[x]/[x]$ undefined near $x = 0$ from the right.

Comment: So , if [x]=0 , then sin[x]/[x] is 0/0 form. And we can use L'HOSPITAL'S rule that results 1.

Comment: So, can I say that the right hand limit exists.

Comment: @user634631 You use l'Hopital rule to compute a limit, not to define a function.

Comment: I've got that point. Ok

Answer (score 0):

By left,

$$\forall x\in(-1,0)\;\;\; \sin(\lfloor x\rfloor)=\sin(-1)$$
so, $$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{\sin(\lfloor x\rfloor)}{\lfloor x\rfloor} =\sin(1)$$

By right,

$$\forall x\in(0,1) \;\;\; \lfloor x\rfloor =0=\sin(\lfloor x\rfloor)$$

so, the function $x\mapsto \frac{\sin(\lfloor x\rfloor)}{\lfloor x\rfloor}=\frac 00 $ is not well defined on the right of $ 0 $ and we cannot speak about right limit